# My cart product add and subtract is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Here is my jquery-code in my cart for adding and deleting products. But it doesn't changes the quantity and one more error I am getting is after adding to the cart it shows me the amount of two items. E.g.: If my item's price is $45 it shows me $90

Any lead for this highly appreciable.

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="product_1338_19903_0_0" class="cart_item last_item first_item address_0 odd">

    <td class="ct-wishList-image">
      <img style="width:100px;" src="admin/itempics/<?php echo $row['itemno']?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row['model_name']?>">
    </td>
    <td class="ct-wishList-description">
      <p class="boughItemId">
        <?php echo $row[ 'itemno']; ?>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="ct-wishList-description">
      <p class="product-name">
        <a href="">
          <?php echo $row[ 'model_name']?>
        </a>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td class="ct-wishList-price">
      <?php echo $row[ 'price'] ?>,00 kr</td>
    <td class="cart_quantity text-center">
      <input class="itemBoughtQty" type='text' name='qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>' size="2" id='qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>' value="1" />
      </br>
      <input type='button' onclick="subchange<?php echo $items_id; ?>()" name='subtract' value='-' />
      <input type='button' onclick="addchange<?php echo $items_id; ?>()" name='add' value='+' />
      <script>
        $(function() {
          var nTotalCount = 0;
          var szUrlString = "index.php?con=6&itemid=";

          $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
            nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);

          });
          $(".boughItemId").each(function(tag) {
            szUrlString += $(this).html() + ",";
          });

          szUrlString += "&qty=";
          $(".itemBoughtQty").each(function(tag) {
            szUrlString += $(this).val() + ",";
          });
          $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#ptcl").attr("href", szUrlString + "&total=" + nTotalCount);
        });
         //document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML= $total;
        function addchange <?php echo $items_id; ?> () {
          $item_value = document.getElementById("qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>").value++;
          document.getElementById("total_product_price_1338_19903_0<?php echo $items_id; ?>").innerHTML = ($item_value + 1) * <? php echo $row['price'] ?> ;

          //total_price
          var nTotalCount = 0;
          var szUrlString = "index.php?con=6&itemid=";
          $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
            nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);
          });

          $(".boughItemId").each(function(tag) {
            szUrlString += $(this).html() + ",";
          });
          szUrlString += "&qty=";
          $(".itemBoughtQty").each(function(tag) {
            szUrlString += $(this).val() + ",";
          });
          $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
          $("#ptcl").attr("href", szUrlString + "&total=" + nTotalCount);
        }

        function subchange <? php echo $items_id; ?> () {
          $item_count = document.getElementById("qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>").value;
          if ($item_count > 1) {
            $item_value = document.getElementById("qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>").value--;
            document.getElementById("total_product_price_1338_19903_0<?php echo $items_id; ?>").innerHTML = ($item_value - 1) * <? php echo $row['price'] ?> ;
            var nTotalCount = 0;
            $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
              nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);
            });
            $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
            $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
            $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
            $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
            $("#ptcl").attr("href", "index.php?con=6&total=" + nTotalCount);
          }
        }
      </script>
    </td>
    <td id="cart_total" data-title="Total">
      <span itempricetag="1" class="cart_total" id="total_product_price_1338_19903_0<?php echo $items_id; ?>"> <?php echo $row['price'] ; ?>  </span> 
      <td class="ct-wishList-button">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-md del_item<?php echo $items_id; ?>" data-value="<?php echo $key; ?>">X</a>
        <script>
          $(".del_item<?php echo $items_id; ?>").click(function() {
            var delcartvalue = $(this).data('value');
            //alert(delcartvalue);
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "cancel_item.php",
              data: {
                cancelitem: delcartvalue
              },
            });
            $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
            window.location.reload();
          });
        </script>
      </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Should your $item_count check be >= 1? as 1 is a valid number of items as well

Comment: i make it as 1 as minimum in my cart so customer won't decrease it to 0.

Comment: There is really no need to put variables into function names like that.  Variables should be passed to functions.  Anyway, it looks like there is a stray space in your function name function `addchange <? php echo $items_id; ?> () {`.

Comment: still its not working properly ...

Answer (score 0):

```
        <td class="ct-wishList-image">
          <img style="width:100px;" src="admin/itempics/<?php echo $row['itemno']?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $row['model_name']?>">
        </td>
        <td class="ct-wishList-description">
          <p class="boughItemId">
            <?php echo $row[ 'itemno']; ?>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td class="ct-wishList-description">
          <p class="product-name">
            <a href="">
              <?php echo $row[ 'model_name']?>
            </a>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td class="ct-wishList-price">
          <?=$row['price'] ?>,00 kr
          </td>
        <td class="cart_quantity text-center">
          <input class="itemBoughtQty" type='text' name='qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>' size="2" id='qty<?php echo $items_id; ?>' value="1" />
          </br>
          <input type='button' onclick="subchange(<?php echo $items_id; ?>)" name='subtract' value='-' /><? /*subchange<?php echo $items_id; ?>()*/ ?>
          <input type='button' onclick="addchange(<?php echo $items_id; ?>,<?php echo $row['price']; ?>)" name='add' value='+' /><? /*subchange<?php echo $items_id; ?>()*/ ?>
        <script>
            $(function() {
              var nTotalCount = 0;
              var szUrlString = "index.php?con=6&itemid=";

              $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
                nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);

              });
              $(".boughItemId").each(function(tag) {
                szUrlString += $(this).html() + ",";
              });

              szUrlString += "&qty=";
              $(".itemBoughtQty").each(function(tag) {
                szUrlString += $(this).val() + ",";
              });
              $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#ptcl").attr("href", szUrlString + "&total=" + nTotalCount);
            });
             //document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML= $total;
            function addchange (item_id , price) { //  <-here add item_id , price
              var item_value = document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value;// change var item_value = document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value++;
              document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value = Number(item_value)+1;// add

              document.getElementById("total_product_price_1338_19903_0"+item_id).innerHTML = (Number(item_value)+1) * Number(price) ;
                // change "total_product_price_1338_19903_0"+item_id 
                // (Number(item_value)+1) * Number(price)

              //total_price
              var nTotalCount = 0;
              var szUrlString = "index.php?con=6&itemid=";
              $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
                nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);
              });

              $(".boughItemId").each(function(tag) {
                szUrlString += $(this).html() + ",";
              });
              szUrlString += "&qty=";
              $(".itemBoughtQty").each(function(tag) {
                szUrlString += $(this).val() + ",";
              });
              $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
              $("#ptcl").attr("href", szUrlString + "&total=" + nTotalCount);
            }

            function subchange(item_id) {
              var item_count = document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value;
              var price = "<?=$row['price'] ?>";
              if (item_count > 1) {
                document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value = Number(item_count)-1;
                document.getElementById("total_product_price_1338_19903_0"+item_id).innerHTML = (Number(item_count)-1) * Number(price) ;
                var nTotalCount = 0;
                $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
                  nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);
                });
                $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
                $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
                $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
                $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
                $("#ptcl").attr("href", "index.php?con=6&total=" + nTotalCount);
              }
            }
          </script>

        </td>
        <td id="cart_total" data-title="Total">
          <span itempricetag="1" class="cart_total" id="total_product_price_1338_19903_0<?php echo $items_id; ?>"> <?php echo $row['price'] ; ?>  </span> 
          <td class="ct-wishList-button">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-md del_item<?php echo $items_id; ?>" data-value="<?php echo $key; ?>">X</a>
            <script>
              $(".del_item<?php echo $items_id; ?>").click(function() {
                var delcartvalue = $(this).data('value');
                //alert(delcartvalue);
                $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "cancel_item.php",
                  data: {
                    cancelitem: delcartvalue
                  },
                });
                $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
                window.location.reload();
              });
            </script>
          </td>

      </tr>
```

Comment: still same error it returns on adding items it shows price of two products.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="product_1338_19903_0_0" class="cart_item last_item first_item address_0 odd">

           <!-- <td class="ct-wishList-image">
              <img style="width:100px;" src="admin/itempics/item_no.jpg" alt="item_no">
            </td>-->
            <td class="ct-wishList-description">
              <p class="boughItemId">
                    item_no<!--?php echo $row[ 'itemno']; ?-->
              </p>
            </td>
            <td class="ct-wishList-description">
              <p class="product-name">
                <a href="">
                    model_name<!--?php echo $row[ 'model_name']?-->
                </a>
              </p>
            </td>
            <td class="ct-wishList-price">
              10000,00 kr
              </td>
            <td class="cart_quantity text-center">
              <input class="itemBoughtQty" type='text' name='qtyitem_id' size="2" id='qtyitem_id' value="1" />
              </br>
              <input type='button' onclick="subchange('item_id')" name='subtract' value='-' /><!--? /*subchange<?php echo $items_id; ?>()*/ ?-->
              <input type='button' onclick="addchange('item_id',10000)" name='add' value='+' /><!--? /*subchange<?php echo $items_id; ?>()*/ ?-->
            <script>
                $(function() {
                  var nTotalCount = 0;
                  var szUrlString = "index.php?con=6&itemid=";

                  $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
                    nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);

                  });
                  $(".boughItemId").each(function(tag) {
                    szUrlString += $(this).html() + ",";
                  });

                  szUrlString += "&qty=";
                  $(".itemBoughtQty").each(function(tag) {
                    szUrlString += $(this).val() + ",";
                  });
                  $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#ptcl").attr("href", szUrlString + "&total=" + nTotalCount);
                });
                 //document.getElementById("total_price").innerHTML= $total;
                function addchange (item_id , price) { //  <-here add item_id , price
                  var item_value = document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value;// change var item_value = document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value++;
                  document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value = Number(item_value)+1;// add

                  document.getElementById("total_product_price_1338_19903_0"+item_id).innerHTML = (Number(item_value)+1) * Number(price) ;
                    // change "total_product_price_1338_19903_0"+item_id 
                    // (Number(item_value)+1) * Number(price)

                  //total_price
                  var nTotalCount = 0;
                  var szUrlString = "index.php?con=6&itemid=";
                  $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
                    nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);
                  });

                  $(".boughItemId").each(function(tag) {
                    szUrlString += $(this).html() + ",";
                  });
                  szUrlString += "&qty=";
                  $(".itemBoughtQty").each(function(tag) {
                    szUrlString += $(this).val() + ",";
                  });
                  $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
                  $("#ptcl").attr("href", szUrlString + "&total=" + nTotalCount);
                }

                function subchange(item_id) {
                  var item_count = document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value;
                  var price = "10000";
                  if (item_count > 1) {
                    document.getElementById("qty"+item_id).value = Number(item_count)-1;
                    document.getElementById("total_product_price_1338_19903_0"+item_id).innerHTML = (Number(item_count)-1) * Number(price) ;
                    var nTotalCount = 0;
                    $("span[itempricetag='1'").each(function(tag) {
                      nTotalCount = Number($(this).html()) + Number(nTotalCount);
                    });
                    $("#total_price").html(nTotalCount);
                    $("#cart_price").html(nTotalCount);
                    $("#cart_total").html(nTotalCount);
                    $("#total_total").html(nTotalCount);
                    $("#ptcl").attr("href", "index.php?con=6&total=" + nTotalCount);
                  }
                }
              </script>
              
            </td>
            <td id="cart_total" data-title="Total">
              <span itempricetag="1" class="cart_total" id="total_product_price_1338_19903_0item_id"> 10000  </span> 
          </tr>

</tbody>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is sample price is 10000 and $items_id; = item_id